# Is it safe to remove a shared lib while programs which depends on it is executing?

Tags: shared-library, dynamic-linking

Is it allowed to delete (for example, with the `rm` command) some shared library without any danger when programs that depend on it are executed? I thought so, because if the program was running, then all the necessary data from the library was loaded into memory

But I noticed that when I rewrite the library (`echo 123 > somelib.so`), the program that depends on it is destroyed due to a `Bus error`

If the library is already in memory, why is the program crushed because of a change to the library on disk? And if the library is not in memory, then why can it be deleted from the disk and the program will continue execution? Where does it read data from the library from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought so, because if the program was running, then all the necessary data from the library was loaded into memory

Executable data is read **only when needed**, otherwise you'd wait ages for heavy applications like e.g. Google Chrome to launch (its binary is currently `179 134 080` bytes). Also, WinRAR in Windows allows to create self-extractable archives which can be up to `2^64 - 1` is size. No way you'll ever be able to extract them if the kernel needed to load all the code to RAM before launching it.

> If the library is already in memory, why is the program crushed because of a change to the library on disk?

It's not entirely in memory, it's only mapped to the process being executed. It will get cached when the kernel decided to actually execute code from the library but until then it stays solely on your disk drive.

Even when the library has been executed, thus read and cached and it still can be cached out when the kernel is running low on memory.

It's crashing because you've actually replaced the file and the kernel tries to find functions which you're asking to execute. Those functions become rubbish once the file is overwritten, so the application crashes.

> And if the library is not in memory, then why can it be deleted from the disk and the program will continue execution? Where does it read data from the library from?

The Unix architecture used in the Linux kernel allows to delete opened files. Since the number of handles to this file is above zero such a file will **not** be technically removed until the last handle is closed.

> Is it safe to remove a shared lib while programs which depends on it is executing?

Yes, perfectly. Overwriting such a library is not safe. Replacing it is again safe, because the kernel will use the old (deleted) library. This is how you can replace pretty much all libraries without rebooting the system. Only when you replace them you have to restart all the applications which are using them.

Lastly the Linux kernel was patched a few years ago to allow to replace itself on the fly: https://ostechnix.com/5-kernel-live-patching-tools-that-will-help-to-run-linux-servers-without-reboots/

Answer (score 4):

In general, files don't *actually* get deleted when they're removed with `rm`, but only after all open file handles to them are also closed. I'm pretty sure that also applies to when the file is mapped to the memory of some process. After the `rm`, you just can't open the file again, but the data and the mapping stay.

Modifying the file is a different matter, since there's only one "version" of the file data, all reads, writes and shared mapping access the same data. And if you write garbage in there, the processes running code from the file also get garbage. On Linux, you can't do that to an executable file, it gives an error ("Text file busy"), but there's no such protection for shared libraries.

(You can try that: `cp -a /bin/cat /tmp/cat; /tmp/cat &` and then try `echo 123 >> /tmp/cat`. Then `fg` to get the `cat` back, and hit Ctrl-C to close it.)

Technically, one could say that `rm` doesn't really delete files at all, it just removes the filenames. A file can have more than one name, we just call them hard links, but it's basically just multiple names for the same file. The actual removal is often triggered by the last name getting removed, but it's somewhat separate.

Comment: *Technically, one could say that `rm` doesn't really delete files at all, it just removes the filenames. A file can have more than one name, we just call them hard links*  FWIW, the actual [POSIX standard function to remove a file is `unlink()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/unlink.html):  "The unlink() function shall remove a link to a file. ... When the file's link count becomes 0 and no process has the file open, the space occupied by the file shall be freed and the file shall no longer be accessible. If one or more processes have the file open ..."

Comment: Amusingly enough, there’s [an LWN article on `ETXTBSY`](https://lwn.net/Articles/866493/), published yesterday!

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I guess you could also say that a file has at least one link to it, we just call that link a "name"... But other places in POSIX talk about [filenames](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170) and pathnames... The [POSIX description for `rm`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/rm.html) also clearly says "rm - remove directory entries", but the GNU manpage says "rm - remove files or directories", which I guess matches what a lot of users _think_ it does.

Comment: @ilkkachu **there's only one "version" of the file data** why not two? is the library loaded into memory when the CPU executes it? Then there should be the first version on disk, and the second version in memory (it is assumed that the library is small and completely fits in memory)

Comment: @ibse libraries are mapped into memory, they’re not loaded entirely; pages are loaded as required. So there’s only ever one version of the library, the one on disk; parts of if may happen to also be in memory, but that’s only temporary (although it can be for a *very* long time).

Comment: @ibse, what's physically on the disk vs. memory doesn't really matter. The OS might cache the data to memory, so technically you have one copy on disk and one in memory, and they might differ until the data is eventually written back, _but_ it's the job of the OS to provide a consistent view, so if the in-memory copy is modified, it doesn't read the old data from the disk back again. Of course if a process calls `read()` on the file, it gets a private copy and can do what ever it likes without that affecting other processes. [...]

Comment: @ibse, But libraries aren't copied to memory like that, but instead they're mapped with `mmap()`, which basically means giving a direct view to the file data, possibly even direct access to the memory pages that hold the cached file data in the OS. The point of that is that the mappings can be shared, we only need the data in RAM once, but it's visible to multiple processes.